# Ruby on Rails app not loading stylesheet despite it being accessible on the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, freebsd

I'm currently migrating my Ruby on Rails 2.3.8 apps to a new server running Apache 2.2.17 on FreeBSD 8.1 with Passenger 3, Ruby Enterprise Edition 1.8.7. For some reason, despite the stylesheets being accessible, the apps are not loading them. The code is correct and runs fine on the old setup. Has anyone ran into this?

**Update:** Wowwww it was an issue with the version of chromium. All is good after updating. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: what is you passenger configuration ?

Comment: Everything is default except for a few PassengerPreStarts and:
PassengerMinInstances 1
PassengerHighPerformance on
RailsEnv 'production'

However, if these are taken out and everything is left to default I still have the issue. 

LoadModule passenger_module /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   PassengerRoot /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0
   PassengerRuby /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/bin/ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with the edge-version of Chrome I was using... Should have checked another browser before posting.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check on the permissions -- what user is the ruby process running under (for passenger), and does that user have access to the stylesheet in question.

you can use `ls -l` to see permission sets for the stylesheets.

Comment: The permissions and apache user are fine as you can load the file by going to http://host/stylesheets/application.css, however when you go to http://host/, that layout isn't loading the stylesheet for some reason?